# Have I placed "itsu" correctly in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

> きょう の パーティー は **いつなんですか**。

Is placing "itsunandesuka" correct when I'm trying to make a sentence which means "When is today's party" while using the grammar pattern "ndesuka"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position of いつ is correct and there's nothing wrong with your sentence, but it's better to use 何時{なんじ} to ask for *when* in this case.

> 今日{きょう}のパーティーは何時{なんじ}なんですか。

The nuance of using なん is that the topic of the party has already being introduced as opposed to

> 今日{きょう}のパーティーは何時{なんじ}ですか。

Some people could *also* argue that the first sentence is slightly more friendly.

The word いつ is appropriate for any kind of situation and doesn't change depending on **who is** speaking or **who you are** speaking to.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to ask which situations are appropriate for using "itsu".

Comment: いつ **is** always appropriate. いつはいつでもいい！:)

Comment: Adding から "from" may make the sentence sound more natural.<br>

i.e. 今日のパーティーは何時からですか？

Comment: Could you clarify why it's better to use 何時 over いつ?

Comment: Because いつ is __too broad__. When is the party? = Today. And Today is already mentioned in the question, so it would be strange to ask _when_ instead of _what time_. To me it's like asking _so when's today's party?_